# MS Office files looks different in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I asked this question in a different fashion without any constructive replies. Lets change the description and see if someone has an answer:

System / Software (s):
Ubuntu 16.04
Windows 10
MS Office version 2016
LibreOffice Vers. 5.1.1.3
Font: Calibri

It seems fonts are bigger in LibreOffice than windows MS office:

Something that would fit in one line in windows.

Something that would fit in one line in
windows

Top MS Office
Bottom LibreOffice

[image]
[image]

The company logo placed in the Top Text Right side also appears on the top left further down than it should.
Installed the restricted fonts, no difference. (ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

This is not a major issue but it would be nice to move as much work as possible over til Ubuntu so I dont have to fire up the VM every time i need to edit or send something. I need to be able to trust that it will look the same in all platforms.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: I do would like some better screenshots :D

Comment: Hehe, yes i get your point. But the main problem is still visible.

Comment: @seth, this would solve the issue at hand, BUT as i say this will not solve the problem. This is more of a workaround. I cannot migrate to ODF as this causes problems with MS Office opening it correctly or opening it at all.

Comment: @IzznogooooD I only recommended that as a troubleshooting step. If that fixes the issue then likely there is no other fix. Blame MS..

Comment: @seth, I allways blame MS :--)

Comment: Yes, they look different. What's your question?

Comment: @David Forester: #hint: "I need to be able to trust that it will look the same in all platforms"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [user270540's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/750221/158442):

> First of all, according to the license you are allowed to use Calibri
>   only when running Microsoft Office. Second, Calibri has been designed
>   to preserve the metrics information only whit Microsoft Office, so the
>   result that you get is intentional. Third, the free font Carlito is
>   metrically compatible with Calibri but does not have the same legal
>   limitations. You should configure LibreOffice to replace Calibri with
>   Carlito (and Cambria with Caladea) to preserve the visual aspect of
>   the document. Calibri is not part of MS Core Fonts, and is not
>   available for Linux in any legal way. MS C-Fonts, or ClearType fonts,
>   should be avoided as much as possible, even by MS Office users. Please
>   have a look at the patents that cover ClearType fonts, and you will
>   understand why.

If you have Carlito fonts installed its as easy as (If not look further down):
Tools --> Options --> Libreoffice --> Fonts

Make a rule to always replace Calibri with Carlito (and Cambria with Caladea):

[image]

NB: You need to manually type Calibri as you will not have it.

Now if you dont have the fonts you need installed you can search and download them from [www.openfontlibrary.org](http://www.openfontlibrary.org).

You need to extract and change permissions:

```
cd /usr/share/fonts
sudo unzip /home/YourUserName/Downloads/FontName.zip
sudo chmod -R 755 FontName (Directory)
```

You may need to rebuild your font cache:

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

Have fun and good luck! ;)

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2318372

Comment: Thanks! Any idea if there exists a compatible font for Calibri **light**? Carlito does not work apparently in that setting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72860575/font-compatible-with-calibri-light

Answer (score 3):

First of all, according to the license you are allowed to use Calibri only when running Microsoft Office. Second, Calibri has been designed to preserve the metrics information only whit Microsoft Office, so the result that you get is intentional. Third, LibreOffice installs the free font Carlito which is metrically compatible with Calibri but does not have the same legal limitations, and you should configure LibreOffice to replace Calibri with Carlito (and Cambria with Caladea) to preserve the visual aspect of the document. Calibri is not part of MS Core Fonts, and is not available for Linux in any legal way. MS C-Fonts, or ClearType fonts, should be avoided as much as possible, even by MS Office users. Please have a look at the patents that cover ClearType fonts, and you will understand why.

Comment: This would be a great answer if you tell me how to make LibreOffice replace all unsupported fonts with supported fonts, and make the document look the same.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Metric-compatible_fonts

Answer (score 0):

Surely, they would be different. You should have the used font installed on Ubuntu. The rest is a formatting issue, you can copy the formatting rules from the office doc and configure libre office to look the same. It's all manual work as far as I know.

Comment: Do you have any more information? links perhaps?

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)